# Beginner C - trying out functions

Tags: c, function

I tried to write my first function in ANSI C.

The purpose of the function is to get 2 user inputs ( capital , interest_rate ) and to return the result of 'interest_rate * capital' to the main function in which I then try to print out the final result.

My code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

 /* k= Kapital ( capital )
  * i= Zinssatz ( interestrate )
  * s= aufruf der compute funktion
  * 
  */

long compute_interest (long k,long i) {
  printf("Bitte geben Sie Ihr Startkapital ein\n"); /*user input capital*/
  scanf("%ld\n", &k);

  printf("Bitte geben Sie den Zinssatz ein\n"); /*user input intrstrte*/
  scanf("%ld\n", &i);

  return k * i;
}



 long main(void) {
   long s;
   s = compute_interest;
   printf("geld = %ld\n", s);



   return 0;
 }
```

Compiling gives me this error message:

```
    warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast    
    [enabled by default]
    s = compute_interest;
      ^
```

What is my mistake? What should I change?

Comment: just btw. "s" is not the call of "compute_interest" but the result of "compute_interest"

Comment: btw it is int main(void)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are not passing any value to the function, i suggest you leave the function empty. i.e your function should be like this

```
long compute_interest () {

  long k, i;
  printf("Bitte geben Sie Ihr Startkapital ein\n"); /*user input capital*/
  scanf("%ld\n", &k);

  printf("Bitte geben Sie den Zinssatz ein\n"); /*user input intrstrte*/
  scanf("%ld\n", &i);

  return k * i;
}
```

Then to call up the function you have to put the parentheses. i.e

```
long main(void) {
   long s;
   s = compute_interest();
   printf("geld = %ld\n", s);



   return 0;
 }
```

**This must give you the desired results. Hope this helps**

Comment: Unless `k` and `i` are defined globally, that function will not compile.

Comment: Lol - that means "this must not" give the desired result.

Comment: @james thank you for the quick and simple answer ! btw if i wanted to use a double , with what would i replace "%ld" ?

Comment: replace it with "%lf"

Answer (score 4):

You need `()` to make a function call:

```
compute_interest()
```

Additionally, the function takes two arguments, so you need to send them in... for example:

```
compute_interest(2000, 2)
```

Comment: Beware he has longs for params.  .1 won't work well.  Beware they shouldn't really be params anyways as written.

Answer (score 3):

Two issues:

```
s = compute_interest;
```

This doesn't call the function.  Because you omitted the `()`, this actually tries to assign a pointer to the function to `s`.  This is why you're getting the warning.  Do this to call the function:

```
s = compute_interest();
```

Which brings us to the second issue.  You define `compute_interest` to take two parameters, however the value of those parameters is overwritten by the `scanf` calls.

What you really want in this situation is for `k` and `i` to be local variables rather than parameters:

```
long compute_interest () {
  long k, i;

  printf("Bitte geben Sie Ihr Startkapital ein\n"); /*user input capital*/
  scanf("%ld\n", &k);

  printf("Bitte geben Sie den Zinssatz ein\n"); /*user input intrstrte*/
  scanf("%ld\n", &i);

  return k * i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C, function names are treated as pointer to the function itself. `compute_interest` is a function name and its type is `long (*)(long, int)`. `s` is of type `long int` and the assignment `s = compute_interest;` is assigning a pointer to `long` data type and that's the reason why you are getting the warning.
You need to place `()` after `compute_interest` to let the compiler know that its a function call. 
You also need to remove functions parameters `long k,long i` and place it inside the function body.